# Proof or disproof an inequality problem

Tags: calculus, algebra-precalculus, functions, inequality

Known:
$$0<x<1$$
$$0<k<1$$
$$0<x+k<1$$
$$y\geq1$$ $y$ is a whole number.
Prove:
$$
\frac{xy}{1-(1-x)^y}\leq \frac{(x+k)y}{1-(1-(x+k))^y}.
$$

I ran some sample results and the inequality appears to be true. For example:
$((0.005*20)/(1-(1-0.005)^9))<((0.006*20)/(1-(1-0.006)^9 ))
$

Basically, both denominators and numerators increase slightly from left to right, which is not obvious whether or not this will increase the right side. It is obvious that denominators on both sides will be **between 0 and 1**.

Since both denominators have to be positive, I first thought about cross-multiplying but could not countinue to simply further:
 $$
(1-(1-x)^y) ((x+k)y)\leq (xy) (1-(1-(x+k))^y)
$$

Comment: Let $x=10$.  That disproves your inequality $0<x<1$.

Comment: x cannot be 10. 0<x<1

Comment: ... which is why it disproves your assertion $0<x<1$ in your original post.

Comment: 0<x<1 is a condition for the inequality. x cannot be 10. @user10354138

Comment: Where does it say so?  Your post started with no English words, just a list of 5 inequalities of which the second one is $0<x<1$.

Comment: @user10354138 I listed 4 conditions first before the inequality

Comment: Try dervivating over $k$ since the $k=0$ is obvious.

Comment: Cross multiplication is incorrect,

Comment: @WilliamElliot why? Both denominators have to be positive. ref: https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/2979431/does-cross-multiply-always-work-for-inequalities-if-both-denominators-are-both-p/2979487#2979487

Comment: <= is wrong....

Comment: The proof turned out to be very, very simple.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

$$\frac{xy}{1-(1-x)^y}\leq \frac{(x+k)y}{1-(1-(x+k))^y}$$

Introduce $z=x+k$, $z\in(0,1)$. The inequality becomes:

$$\frac{x}{1-(1-x)^y}\leq \frac{z}{1-(1-z)^y}$$

Make another substitution:

$$u=1-x\\v=1-z$$

Obviously, $x<z\implies u>v$. The inequality now becomes:

$${1-u \over 1-u^y}\le{1-v \over 1-v^y}$$

$${1-u \over {(1-u)(1+u+u^2+...+u^{y-1})}}\le {1-v \over {(1-v)(1+v+v^2+...+v^{y-1})}}$$

$${1 \over {1+u+u^2+...+u^{y-1}}}\le {1 \over {1+v+v^2+...+v^{y-1}}}$$

$$1+u+u^2+...+u^{y-1}\ge 1+v+v^2+...+v^{y-1}$$

...which is obviously true for $u>v$ and $y\ge1$.

Comment: Your proof is right for the question as stated, when $y$ is a whole number. But in fact the inequality is true regardless of whether $y\in\mathbb N$, it's true for all real $y\geq 1$, as can be shown with the calculus approach. Still well done though!

Answer (score 1):

**Hint:** We can reframe the problem to showing that the function
$$f_a(x):=\frac{ax}{1-(1-x)^a}$$
is either monotonely increasing or constant on $[0,1]$, which is the same as showing that $f'_a(x)\geq0$. Differentiating:
$$\begin{split}
f'_a(x) = \frac{a(1-(1-x)^a)-a^2x(1-x)^{a-1}}{(1-(1-x)^a)^2}.
\end{split}$$
The denominator is always positive, so we are reduced to showing that whenever $x\in(0,1)$ and $a\geq1$, then
$$ax(1-x)^{a-1}\leq 1-(1-x)^a.$$

Comment: For $x=1$ your inequality is **not** true.

Comment: You're right, the inequality was pointing the wrong way before. Thanks for the correction, it is fixed now.

Comment: I think that I have found a much simpler proof, please check :)